# Image preview on asp:file upload control

Tags: asp.net, image, upload

I have an asp:file upload which I allowed users to select multiple files, I want it that if the user clicks on browse and pressed ok, I want the users to be able to preview the images selected (just like facebook image upload) how can i do this?

Comment: Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214458/how-to-preview-uploaded-image-in-file-upload-control-before-save-using-asp-net-o you can loop through all selected files and create dynamically previews before to upload them to the server.

Answer (score 2):

[image: I thing this is helpful you]

http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/165544/Display-Image-Preview-without-saving-file-physically-after-upload-in-ASPNet/

also refer this link...........

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"
 style="top: 256px; left: 533px; position: absolute; height: 23px; width: 217px" ForeColor="White" />

<asp:Button ID="btnset" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="Medium" style="top: 309px; left: 605px; position: absolute; height: 26px; width: 81px" Text="Set Photo " />

<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" style="top: 66px; left: 568px; position: absolute; height: 152px; width: 136px" BorderColor="#CCCCFF" BorderStyle="Ridge" />
```

**VB Code :**

```
Protected Sub btnset_Click(ByVal sender As Object, 
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnset.Click
        Image2.ImageUrl = FileUpload1.FileName
 End Sub
```